# How can i return an object based on scope of on authorized user using spring AOP

Tags: jpa, spring-security, authorization, spring-aop, aspect

So here's my challenge, I have a method that returns a list of objects from the database using JPA. I want to to be able to filter the response of that method using a custom Annotation and Spring AOP.

One way would be to Hijack the response using the @Around annotation, proceed() and filter the response of that function. but that's poor implementation and wouldn't scale.

So is there a better way to actually implement this aspect and have the advised method only return results based on scope without changing code in the method to be advised?

Edit...

I have a controller with an endpoint that returns list of persons from the database.

```
@Autowired
TestService service;

@RequestMapping("/get")
@AuthorizeAndFilter
public List<Person> getAll() {
    return service.getall();
}
```

I want to be able to create a custom @AuthorizeAndFilter annotation and have it execute in this order.

1. Make sure the Authenticated principal has permissions to make this call or throw a 403 exception.
2. Instead of returning all persons in the database, it should return only persons from same region as the authenticated user.

Comment: Spring AOP can only advice a bean method  - before , after or around ( before and after ) - during its execution. It cannot advice within the method execution phase. From what I understand the question here is to modify the adviced method logic , which is not possible through spring AOP.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, your question is completely unclear and ambiguous. Nobody can debug prose and nobody likes to guess or speculate what exactly you might want to do. So please and with all due respect, present both application and advice code in order to clarify your question. Ideally, present an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which would drastically improve your chances of getting a helpful answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: The first part of the question mentions ‘@Around’ wouldn’t scale . Can we assume you have already implemented this code and discarded the same. Is your requirement to have an alternative for ‘@Around’?

Comment: @R.G what i means was that, having to filer the return value wouldn't scale because imagine the getAll() method is returning a list with size 100. then after filtering, it becomes size 5.
Isn't there a way to just inject the region parameter and get the filtered list once instead?

Comment: @dexterio without modifying service.getAll() method , is it ? To understand , why not add an argument to the getAll() method to pass the region and use the same in the query downstream?

Comment: Do you mean that it is suboptimal to fetch all results and then filter after the fact? Do you want to make sure the database (or whatever data source) request already limits via request parameters? Then you ought to intercept at the point where that call is made, not here where you already receive all results. If I misunderstood you and filtering the full list here is okay, then I don't understand your problem. Like you said, it can be done easily in an `@Around` advice.